# In JavaScript, can you use toLowerCase() after a variable is declared in a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I use toLowerCase() in JavaScript, I seem to always have problems such as typeError: "x" is not a function.

**Ex.**

```
var x = "Pie";
if (x.toLowerCase() = "pie") {
 // Code isn't executed
}
```

Comment: You can call `.toLowerCase()` on any string, but you can't assign that equal to something (the code shown would give the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"). Change `=` to `===` or `==` for comparison.

Comment: Your code doesn't exhibit your stated problem. But it is an error because you are using `=` which is assignment instead of `==` (or `===`) which is comparison.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
var x = "Pie";
if (x.toLowerCase() == "pie") {
  // Code isn't executed
}
```

notice the double equal (`==`) or you can use (`===`).